# replace text in inputs and textareas if there is an error during form validation

Tags: php, html, validation

I need to replace the text in a textarea after a form has been submitted but hasn't passed the validation.

I am able to do this if i have the php in the same file quite easily with

```
<?php echo escape(Input::get('comment')); ?>
```

but the issue arises when i need to use the form action to do the validation through another file which i need to due to the way google recaptcha works...

I'm thinking i will need to post back from the validation file the text the user entered? and if so how would i go about selecting which field the appropriate text should go in?

thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: you could use an AJAX post to submit the form to the other file without leaving the page

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is. I have used Google recaptcha before and it doesn't need posting to another file if you don't want it to, you can just include the necessary stuff.

Comment: i'll go with the ajax thanks @marc and if i include the google recaptcha php within the same file the form doesn't load jeroen.